# listview scolling in android is slow

Tags: android, listview

i have a listview with a heavy inflation of three different custom rows .From these rows i  have to collect data and fill the database and finally get that data also .Now the problem is that the number of rows created depends upon user it may b as high as 100. And my list becomes very slow in scrolling .Now what i want to know is will it be helpful to put all of my list functioning in Async task i mean its creation as well as its execution. below is my code snippet.

```
         private class Async extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     lv.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapterAB(Measure_New.this));
                        new EfficientAdapterAB(Measure_New.this).notifyDataSetChanged();
            //stuff that updates ui

                }
            });

            return null;
        }

     }


    private   class EfficientAdapterAB extends BaseAdapter {
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;
            View[] view; 
            ViewHolderAB holderAB;
            /*  RadioButton[] ob=new RadioButton[n];
              RadioButton[] ra=new RadioButton[n];*/

             AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(Measure_New.this);
                SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getReadableDatabase();
                String q="SELECT * FROM ab_measurement WHERE job_id=" +"\""+Settings.jobid +"\"";
                Cursor  cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(q,null);



             public EfficientAdapterAB(Context context) {
             mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


             }

             public int getCount() {
                System.out.println("in getcount value of n is "+n);

                view = new View[n+2];
                return n+2;
             }

             public Object getItem(int position) {

             return position;
             }

             public long getItemId(int position) {

             return position;
             }


 public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final RadioButton[] ob=new RadioButton[n];
    final  RadioButton[] ra=new RadioButton[n];



     holderAB = new ViewHolderAB();
     final EditText edit_a_ft,edit_a_inch,edit_b_ft,edit_b_inch,edit_ab_a_ft,edit_ab_a_inch,edit_ab_b_ft,edit_ab_b_inch;

if (view[position] == null) {
        if(position==0){
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.measure_upper_bar, null);
             txt_ft_mtr=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ft_mtr);
             txt_inch_cm=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_inch_cm);
             if(Settings.metric_count==1){
                 txt_ft_mtr.setText(""+"Meter");
                 txt_inch_cm.setText(""+"Centimeter");
             }
             user_input= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Num_edittxt_measure_new);
             gettingUserInput();
             new EfficientAdapterAB(Measure_New.this).notifyDataSetChanged();
             System.out.println("after gettinguserInput value of n is "+n);
              feet=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Feet_edittxt);
              inch =(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Inches_Edittxt);

              feet.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                    val_feet_baseline=Integer.parseInt(feet.getText().toString());

                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }

                }
            });

             inch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{

                        val_inch_baseline=Integer.parseInt(inch.getText().toString());

                        if(val_inch_baseline>=ft_mtr){
                            inch_greater=true;
                            ft_baseline=val_feet_baseline+(val_inch_baseline/ft_mtr);
                            val_inch_baseline=val_inch_baseline%ft_mtr;
                            feet.setText(""+ft_baseline);
                            inch.setText(""+val_inch_baseline);
                            System.out.println("yes its working values of feet and inch is "+"feet"+ft_baseline+"inch"+val_inch_baseline);

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            });

             if(inch_greater==true){
                 baseline_length=String.valueOf(ft_baseline).concat(".").concat(String.valueOf(val_inch_baseline));
                 feet.setText(""+ft_baseline);
                 System.out.println("in the if part");
                 inch_greater=false;
             }
             else{
             baseline_length=String.valueOf(val_feet_baseline).concat(".").concat(String.valueOf(val_inch_baseline));
             System.out.println("in the else part");
             feet.setText(""+val_feet_baseline);
             }

             inch.setText(""+val_inch_baseline);
                if(val_feet_baseline==0){
                     feet.setText(""+"");
                }

                if(val_inch_baseline==0){

                    inch.setText(""+"");
                }
             user_input.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        user_input.setText("");
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(user_input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

                        ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);



                    }
                });

                rb_A = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_A);
                rb_B = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_B);
                rb_AB = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_A_B);

                rb_A.setOnClickListener(Measure_New.this);
                rb_B.setOnClickListener(Measure_New.this);
                rb_AB.setOnClickListener(Measure_New.this); 




             view[position] = convertView; 

        }

         else if(position==n+1){

                convertView=mInflater.inflate( R.layout.details_continue_btn, null);
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Continue).setOnClickListener(Measure_New.this);
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_exit_restart).setOnClickListener(Measure_New.this);

                view[position] = convertView;
           }
        else{   


                     if(optn_checkd==1){

                         setDatabase();

                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.a_xml, null);
                     txt_A_ft_mtr=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_A_ft_mtr);
                     txt_A_inch_cm=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_A_inch_cm);
                     if(Settings.metric_count ==1){
                         txt_A_ft_mtr.setText(""+"A(m.)");
                         txt_A_inch_cm.setText(""+"A(cm.)");
                     }


                     holderAB.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
                     holderAB.text.setText(""+(position));



                     edit_a_ft=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText_A_ft);
                     edit_a_inch=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText_A_inch);

                     if(position<=n){
                     textChangeListenerForFeet(edit_a_ft,position,al_edit_A_ft);
                     textChangeListenerForInch(edit_a_inch,edit_a_ft,position,al_edit_A_inch);
                     }

                     System.out.println("in else value of position before crashing is"+position+"  "+(position-1)+"  "+ n);
                     if(position<=n){
                     ob[position-1]=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_Obstruction_a);
                     ob[position-1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(radio__ob_flag[position-1]==true){
                                ob[position-1].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.redioon);
                                obstruction/*[position-1]*/="Y";

                                radio__ob_flag[position-1]=false;
                            }
                            else{
                                ob[position-1].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.rediooff);
                                radio__ob_flag[position-1]=true;
                                obstruction/*[position-1]*/="N";

                            }
                             try{
                                    al_ob_a.add(position-1,obstruction/*[position-1]*/);

                                        al_ob_a.remove(position);


                                    }catch(Exception e){

                                    }

                            System.out.println("wooooow here i am ob"+al_ob_a);
                        }
                    });
                     }

                     if(position<=n){
                     ra[position-1]=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_Raisedwall_a);
                     ra[position-1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                            if(radio__ra_flag[position-1]==true){
                                ra[position-1].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.redioon);

                                radio__ra_flag[position-1]=false;
                                obstruction/*[position-1]*/="Y";

                            }
                            else{
                                ra[position-1].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.rediooff);
                                radio__ra_flag[position-1]=true;
                                obstruction/*[position-1]*/="N";

                            }

                             try{
                                    al_ra_a.add(position-1,obstruction/*[position-1]*/);

                                    al_ra_a.remove(position);

                                    }catch(Exception e){

                                    }


                            System.out.println("wooooow here i am ra "+al_ra_a);
                        }
                    });
                     }

                     if(getttingFromDbForMeasure()==true){
                    if(position<=n){

                       retainingInput(al_edit_A_ft,position,edit_a_ft);
                       retainingInput(al_edit_A_inch,position,edit_a_inch);
                       retainingInputForRadio( al_ob_a,position,ob);
                       retainingInputForRadio(al_ra_a ,position,ra);


                    }
                     }

                     }
```

Comment: setAdapter() not need to be in thread, its getView() in adapter class which take time to populate view on list

Comment: so what else i can do to use async task in this case??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You need to utilize convertView in Yours adapter getView(). This would let You use view holder. Currently You only assign values to viewHolder, but not set it as tag or retrieve values back (to avoid redundant findViewById calls).

Checkout [this Google I/O video from Romain Guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) and, also checkout [the code](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf) from that session slides.